# Is it possible to have vim use different colors than the iTerm profile?

Tags: vim, iterm2

My vim currently uses the colors defined by my current iTerm profile.

Is it possible to have vim use a separate set of defined colors? This way I could have one look for my terminal and a different look for my vim.

Comment: you mean colorschemes? http://vimcolors.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim has many color schemes. You can use :colorscheme, then hit tab, to cycle through the ones you currently have available. If you want more, you can search the web and put them in your .vim folder under ".vim/colors". You can take a look at my setup here: https://github.com/Dfenestrator/vimide Which includes many alternate color schemes.

Comment: yes, i know this. For some reason a color scheme that was available through tab completion was either not loading properly or was somehow set to use the ANSI colors of iTerm. I tried using the other color schemes though and they do work.